# Youtube php api get video playlist

Tags: php, api, youtube

I use PHP YouTube API.

```
$youtube = new Madcoda\Youtube\Youtube(array('key' => 'API key'));
$video = $youtube->getVideoInfo('rie-hPVJ7Sw');
```

Return more data, but playlist id is not show.

How can I find out which playlist a video is in?

Comment: As there are an unlimited number of playlists containing the video and some may be unlisted or even private, for privacy reasons you can't get all playlists the video is in.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. One video can be in many playlists and I don't think YouTube will return those data. See [the doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).

Comment: Completely understandable.  Thanks!